# Visual Basic 2013 "Expression expected."

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have problem on this line:

```
TextBox1.Text = '0'
```

More code:

```
Private Sub Button18_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button18.Click
    TextBox1.Text = '0'
End Sub
```

I getting error Expression expected.

Comment: This is Visual Basic .NET code, not C++.

Comment: Oh, sorry I just learning. :)

Comment: Add `Option Strict On` to the top of your code file or set this option  in your project properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been a while since I worked with VB but I'm pretty sure you need to use double quotes so this line:

```
TextBox1.Text = '0'
```

should be:

```
TextBox1.Text = "0"
```

Comment: This is because '0' is a character, whilst "0" is a string

Answer (score 0):

Me.OtrosTableAdapter.Update1(id:=@id,nombre:=@Nombre,precio:=@Precio,Entrad:=@Entrad,salid:=@salid) 
which is the error?
Every time I go to compile , it fails with the "@ "

Comment: is in visual studio 2010